# У меня возникеєт ошибка в коде

Tags: python, pygame

```
name = [
"Pygame","PYgame","pYGame","pyGAme","pygAMe","pygaME","pygamE",
]

_name_ = len(name) - 1

play = True

while play:

   pygame.display.set_caption(name[index])
   if index == 0:
    index += 1
    turn = 1
   elif turn == 1:
    index += 1
   elif index == _name_ :
    index = 0

   events = pygame.event.get()
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\program\games>python3 DZ-1.py
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DZ-1.py", line 26, in <module>
    pygame.display.set_caption(name[index])
IndexError: list index out of range

C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\program\games>
```

Comment: Какая ошибка у вас возникает ?  Опубликуйте полный текст ошибки и в какой строке она возникает.

Comment: В чём смысл этого скрипта?

Comment: он должен менят заголовок окна

Comment: Просто сделайте `pygame.display.set_caption(name[index % len(name)])`, тогда последнюю ветку `if` можно будет убрать.

Comment: спасибо но тогда я не смогу закритивать окно на хрестик или Alt+F4

Comment: чему равен `index` на самой первой итерации цикла?

Comment: нулю а что ????

Comment: @StanislavDidus, ты уверен?

Comment: .......да......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в строках

```
elif turn == 1:
    index += 1
```

После того как `turn` стал равен единице на первой итерации, выполнение до

```
elif index == _name_ :
    index = 0
```

не доходит и значение индеса никогда не сбрасывается.

Для решения эту проверку надо делать всегда.

Comment: Все работаєт но когда я нажимаю на хрестик чтоби закончить програму она зависаєт и мне нужно закривать єє через консоль.

Comment: Я уже исправил ошибку спасибо помог.